# SaveAs method - path too long?

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I've encountered a problem with `workbook.SaveAs` method in excel VBA.
the code that I had was: `wb.SaveAs Replace(path & pred & Left(itm.Filename, Len(itm.Filename) - cnt) & "csv", " ", "_"), xlCSV`, where the `Replace` function evaluated to: `"C:\Users\name.surname\Downloads\attTools\attExtractor\ETLBoxUpload\Somefile111_file.csv"` (length exactly the same as in actual file). When method SaveAs is executed I got "`Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed`" error. I fixed the problem by moving files to other directory ( shorter path) : `"C:\Users\name.surname\Desktop\attExtractor\ETLBoxUpload\somefile111_file.csv"`. I did not make any other changes of any kind in the code or anywhere. **So, here's my question: Is it possible that there is restricted length of a string/path passed to SaveAs method? If so, what's the max length?** ( I've tried to google it but with no success)

Comment: Windows due to compatibility reason limit paths to 260 chars. As Windows supports paths up to 32K, you prepend a path with ` \\?\ ` to indicate to turn off Windows path checks.

Comment: but the 1st path was only 87 characters long...

Comment: True but my statement answers your specific question. So Wrap the function in `On Error Resume Next` and `msgbox` out `err.number`, `err.source`, and `err.description`. Pressing Ctrl + C in a message box copies the contents to the clipboard.

Comment: MsgBox says:`---------------------------
Microsoft Excel
---------------------------
1004

VBAProject

Application-defined or object-defined error
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------`

Comment: Can you manually save a file to the first location?

Comment: @jkpieterse Yes I can

Comment: I would suggest unwinding you statement. So assign each part of your statement to a different Variable. IE `a = replace( etc)`. Also the `Len` etc.

Comment: It might be the period in 'name.surname'. Can you try saving to another path? Make it equally long if you like but i don't think string length is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. I've just figured out what was the problem, and it's one of those "I'm so stupid" errors. As you can see I'm using the `Replace` function to get rid of spaces and put "_" instead, it turns out that there is a space in the directory here `...\attTools\...` and not only in the file name. That's why it couldn't find the path....      Sorry I bothered you guys.

Comment: @ACatInLove, I tried your method, but it still did not work for me. Do you know why? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Start with something really small & easy:

- Create a new Excel workbook and save it to your desktop;
- Put the following code in it:

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs wb.Path & "_new", xlCSV
End Sub
```

- See whether it works;
- If it works, increase the code, adding the replace parts;

---

Concerning this question:

*Is it possible that there is restricted length of a string/path passed to SaveAs method? If so, what's the max length?*

No, the string is not restricted by length. However, as mentioned in the comment by @ACatInLove - "Windows due to compatibility reason limits paths to 260 chars."